# Enabling office 365 logins on non-azure virtual machines

Tags: office365, active-directory, azure, azure-activedirectory

I'm kind of clueless here so please bare with my mistakes.

We are using Office 365 and our user accounts and resources seems to be listed in the Microsoft 365 admin page (and it looks like there is some kind of active directory enabled there).

We have a few on premise computers and cloud based virtual servers (not Azure) and we would love to be able to log on to these using our office 365 credentials if possible.

I've tried to read up on "AD Connect", "Azure Active Directory" and "Azure AD Domain Services" but I'm kind of struggling with what I need and how we are supposed to this.

Please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I can point you in the right direction, but cannot test if it works.

See the article
[Associate an Office 365 tenant with an Azure subscription](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/billing-add-office-365-tenant-to-azure-subscription.md).

This article claims that the procedure is very easy, and it walks you through it
with screenshots at every step.

Heavier background documentation about the subject is available from Microsoft at
[Microsoft 365 identity models and Azure Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/about-microsoft-365-identity?view=o365-worldwide).

Comment: thanks for the tips, but these links seem to cover different things?

Comment: In that case, clarify your question, with screenshots wherever possible.

Comment: well, the first link is way outdated and its pretty much impossible to follow those instructions. Its for a way outdated version of Azure Portal.